# Trouble With Display Condition? (Objects in A List)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function to display a list based on whether the objects within are VIP or not. If my VIP flag is true, I want to only display those lockers. If it's false, I want to display every locker, including the VIP ones. Here is what I've got:

```
void SelfStorageList::dispLockers(bool vipOnly) {

if (vipOnly) {

    for(LockerNode *p = head; p !=0; p = p->next) {
        if(p->objLocker.isVip) {

        cout << p->objLocker.lockerId << "," << p->objLocker.renterName << "," << p->objLocker.monthlyRent << "," << p->objLocker.isVip << "," << p->objLocker.isRentOverdue << "\n"; 

        return;

        }

        else {

        return;

        }

    }

    for(LockerNode *p = head; p !=0; p = p->next) {

        cout << p->objLocker.lockerId << "," << p->objLocker.renterName << "," << p->objLocker.monthlyRent << "," << p->objLocker.isVip << "," << p->objLocker.isRentOverdue << "\n";

    }

}


}
```

Apologies for the very long line. I think it should work, but it seems to miss some cases based on my varying simple tests. Can anyone offer any advice? Have I perhaps made the condition too simple?

It should be noted that head points to the first locker in the list, and next is a pointer to the next locker, as I'm sure you'd have guessed.

Comment: When does it fail, and what happens when it fails?

Comment: It will build and run fine. Just seems to be a logical issue. Like, say, for a multi-element list of all VIP, it won't print correctly, it just prints one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `return` statements, the first `for` loop will print at most 1 element, that is, if the head element has the isVip flag set, it will print it. Then, it will return.

Comment: Oooh, that would do it. I was returning simply because I wanted to ensure I didn't print any non-VIP part of the list after printing the VIP parts. If I change to a while condition, can I eliminate my return?

Comment: Of course you can. You are the coder, you can do anything you like :)
Personally, I would leave the for loop in there, combine the two "for" loops in one, and make cout conditional on some combination of vipOnly and .isVip

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, would that make logical sense? Reviewing my code with your words in mind, I have taken out the return in the for loop itself, since it was needless. But based on my current structure, I feel I still need the return in the else statement for the code to function properly, yet I still have logical errors.